# $event.stopPropagation(); not working on firefox

Tags: angularjs, button, cross-browser, event-propagation

```
    <li ng-repeat="chat in openedChats track by $index" ng-click="init($index,'maximize')" role="button">
        <button class="minimized-chat-box" >
        <label style="float:left;color:white"><strong>{{chat.NAME}}</strong></label>
        <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:white;float:right;font-size:14px;" role="button" ng-click="init($index,'close');$event.stopPropagation();">
        </i>
        <i class="fa fa-window-maximize" style="color:white;float:right;font-size:14px" role="button" ng-click="init($index,'maximize');$event.stopPropagation();">
        </i>
        </button>
    </li>
```

This is the code I have for making the icons inside the button clickable and it works fine on chrome, It stops working on firefox, Is there a way I can modify it to work on both. I really couldnt find one way to make it work for both!

Thanks in advance. I'm new to angularjs and I'd love to use angular to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$scope.init = function($event,$index,'maximize'){
$event.stopPropagation();
};
```

then call this like

```
ng-click="init($event,$index,'close')
```

Comment: how about $event.preventDefault()?

Comment: none of them seem to work on firefox, it just works fine on chrome though